# For every two, natural numbers, difference between them exists

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Let $n,m\,{\in}\,\mathbb{N}$.

Then we know that $n\,{\preceq}\,m\,{\lor}\,m\,{\preceq}\,n$. For the purpose of this question, let's call the preceding element $n$ and the succeeding one $m$.

Let $d\,{\in}\,\mathbb{N}:n+d=m$ be called difference.

How do we  know that ${\forall}n,m\,{\exists}d$?

Comment: The answer to this can be found [in section 4 on this page](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/seqser/constrnaturals.html).

Answer (score 1):

Let $n \leq m$; we will show that $m-n$ exists.

This is proved by induction on $m$. Firstly, if $m = 0$ then $n$ must also be $0$, so the difference certainly exists and is $0$.

Now, for arbitrary $m \geq 1$ and $n \leq m$, we have $m-n$ "=" $(m-1) - (n-1)$, so we are done by induction. (Strictly you should split into two cases: $n=0$ and $n \geq 0$. In the former case, the result is trivial: $d=m$. Now for the latter, argue that $d = (m-1) - (n-1)$ exists by induction, and then show that $d$ works for $m-n$; I did it backwards because that's how I came up with it.)

Comment: What if $n=0$ ? ;)

Comment: Shush, you :) I don't need no rigour.